# Why does gnome-software have a red border? Is it sandboxed?

Tags: fedora, gnome

I'm running Fedora 31 and for a while now I've noticed that applying updates via gnome-software doesn't appear to work. It applies them, gets me to reboot and then continues to complain about them not being updated.

I normally apply updates via 'sudo dnf update' and this works fine but occasionally when the OS complains about updates I just click the link in the message to go to the update page of gnome-software.

Software has a red border around it like this[image: gnome-software with a red border around it]

What does it mean? I pressume it's sandboxed? How can I fix it? Bonus points if you can tell me why this happened.

Comment: A red border around GTK apps usually means some sort of CSS in the GTK theme and versions. Does “dnf upgrade” work file?    I’ve also seen it used in Qubes which uses Fedora for its templatevms, and it uses borders for identifying different vms.